# How to check the size of a directory and print it in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, filesystems

How can I check the size of a specific directory in Linux(CentOS) and print it out?

I know I can use `lvs` and `df`(`df -f "path to dir"`) but how can I get just a number like 78Gbs instead of the whole thing(avail, used, etc)

Comment: `while-thing|cut or awk`  or `du -sk somedir`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the size of a directory without any other info:

```
$ du -sh path/to/dir | awk '{print $1}'
118M
```

To get the size of a partition:

```
$ df -h /home | tail -n1 | awk '{print $2}'
14G
```

The `tail` gets rid of the header and `awk` prints just the size of the partition.  On the other hand, if you want just the amount of space *used* on the partition:

```
$ df -h /home | tail -n1 | awk '{print $3}'
11G
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `du` instead of `df`. Check [du manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/du)!

```
du -hs /directory
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean `du -sh` ? Depending on your need you may use other options

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `du` command.

To get the grand total of the arguement(s):

```
du -c
```

Same as above, but only print the summary:

```
`du -sc`
```

If wanted, you can throw in a `-h` in there too with the same effect as with dh